# ajax send variables, sometimes unable to retrieve perfect value in php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have pass this variables to php page

```
 type: 'POST',
 url:   url',
 data: "id="+id+"&nowrole="+role+"&last="+last+"&title="+title+"&devlopdes="+devlopdes
```

sometimes, first set of values are

```
id=1234
role=staff
last=45
title=check page
developdes= view this
http://hibihi.com/index.php?act=view&id=1
http://hibihi.com/index.php?act=add&shipperid=1
```

in php page

retrieve id="1http://hibihi.com/index.php?act=add" not retrieving passing 'id' value

sometimes, second set of values are

```
id=1234
role=staff
last=45
title=check page
developdes= view this
http://hibihi.com/index.php?act=view
http://hibihi.com/index.php?act=add&shipperid=1
```

retrieve correct id=1234 value.

Comment: Please post in your question the individual values of the variables `id` , `role` ... and so on for all the variables when the url is formed wrong ! I am sure the values in you variables is causing the url to break with worng parameter values

Comment: encodeUriComponent() is your friend

Comment: @john Smith: ok.. I will try this...

Comment: If you're using $_POST, try using JSON.stringify.  If you put all your variables in a an object and use the JSON methods, it is extremely easy to send large data to a PHP script and then use jsondecode in PHP to access each variable.  NOTE: does not work on IE8 or lower.

Comment: @john Smith: Thanks... encodeURIComponent() is working. retrieve correct value.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an object, you could simply use this code in javascript:

```
var obj = {};
obj[id]         = "1234";
obj[role]       = "staff";
obj[last]       = "45";
obj[title]      = "check page";
obj[developdes] = "view this";
obj[http1]      = "http://hibihi.com/index.php?act=view&id=1";
obj[http2]      = http://hibihi.com/index.php?act=add&shipperid=1";
```

Then

```
type: 'POST',
url:   url',
data: JSON.stringify(obj)
```

And for your PHP

```
$json = jsondecode($_POST[data]);
$id = $json->{'id'};
```